# Error trying to get all documents from a collection in Firestore in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to get all documents in a collection using this snippet from their documentation. The Firestore and Firebase instance is setup and imported

```
const querySnaphot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Chat"));

querySnaphot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
})
```

I got this error as a response:

> Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project *** before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting (link to Google cloud api I don't have permission for) then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: That suggests you've probably set up your `db` using the wrong project ID.

Comment: @BeratK2 As your issue has fixed you can post the solution for the same so other community members will also get help from this.